# Modify size .ext4 file

Tags: partitioning, mount, ext4

I'm currently trying to modify the partition table for an embedded platform. One of the files flashed towards the platform is an `.ext4` file. I can mount the file, but I can't increase it's size.

GParted can't open `.ext4` files or access them when mounted. I can change the data inside the file. How do I modify it's size?

Mounting and filling up with additional data does not work, since the file is somehow size limited. I suspect I can modify that size in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `kpartx` to be able to use embeded partition in files. For example:

```
sudo kpartx -a ubuntu-15.04.iso
```

Will give you additional devices under `/dev/mapper` like `/dev/mapper/loop0p1`, ... that you can mount.

This might not be needed in your case as to grow your partition, I suggest (do backup):

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=500 >> yourfile.ext4
```

to **append some zero** at the end of your **unmounted** file. And then proceed to **grow** the ext4 fs with

```
resize2fs yourfile.ext4
```

Comment: +1 for pointing me to `kpartx`, but this basically mounts the filesystem. It does allow me to access the boot partition, but all except one file on that are unreadable. It does not point me to a filesize header AFAIK.

Comment: More information on your exact setup would help.

Comment: I usually flash the .ext4 together with .hddimg with the same name and 20 other files (plus a u-boot-envs directory) to an embedded platform. `dd` and resizing didn't do the trick. What else do you require?

Comment: may be try `fdisk` to modify the partition table. or `gdisk` if it's GPT

Comment: @Mast, If the image is already partitioned and you access the partitions with `kpartx`, then you need to run `resize2fs` on the partition device, not the file.  Before you use kpartx though, you need to use `parted` on the file to `resize` the partition.

Comment: @psusi I only have control over the size of the `.ext4` while it's not flashed, otherwise I'd just have `parted` on the end result. The flashing goes over serial and I have no idea if `parted` can handle that.

Comment: @Mast, I'm only talking about the file before it is flashed...

Comment: What is inside your .ext4 ? what is the fileformat ? When I say more information, it is basically something like. What is the output of `file yourfile.ext4` ? what is the output of `fdisk -l yourfile.ext4`

Comment: "dd and resizing didn't do the trick". Why ? what went wrong ?

Comment: @solsTiCe The file got larger as expected, but it wasn't noticeable in the mounted system. Resize didn't help. I suspect repartitioning might help, currently trying that.

Comment: You need to run dd **and** resize2fs